# PHP and SQL, auto-create chart for each data source from database

Tags: php, sql, dynamic, charts, auto-populate

I am new to PHP and SQL and my apologies if this question was asked here already, but I couldn't find it.

Basically, I have multiple sensors which are registered in a SQL database and they all are giving me data. I am able to get data from all of them and plot data into the charts using chart.js.

Now, I wonder if there is a way to automatically create a chart for each sensor, instead of hardcoding each graph for each sensor. In short, I want to get to the stage, when a new sensor is added to database, it would create a chart on my PHP dashboard (using classes or something) for new senor without needing to extra code.

Comment: Just tagged each sensor with unique ID and query the DB. Then sort everything based on the sensor tag. So, each time new sensor is added, just tagged it with unique ID

Comment: Thank you @zimorok, this is great. Do you know of any web links which would give me some pointers on where and how to start implementing it? I came across on how to do it using React, Javascript and Jquery, but not in PHP. Hence I wonder if I can do it. 

Again, I am very new to PHP and SQL, so any pointers would be a massive help.

Comment: The first thing u need to do is to actually make changes on how u send the data to ur DB because this will be the entry point of the data from each sensor. If u cannot do that, u have to manually add unique tag for each sensor. If u can show us how ur DB structure, it will be easy

Comment: My database is okay. It won't allow me to add screenshot. Its only one table. Columns are named in following:

DATA_ID
SENSOR_ID -> IP address of device
LOCATION
TEM_DATA
DATE_OF_DATA

It stores okay. 

I have 20 Sensors, and I wonder if I can create a class or something, in PHP, which would take all those 20 sensors, and create 20 charts with data for each sensor.

Comment: Dude, ur DB already have SENSOR_ID which I presume unique to each sensor. U can create a class that fetch the data and loop through it. For easier looping, you can group the data by SENSOR_ID first through SQL then easily go through the data again with PHP to make the chart

Comment: I probably didn't make clear on what is it I am after. 

I am after creating a php program, which would automatically create a charts with data in it, when there is a new sensor added to database. 

So each time sensor is added to database, I want my dashboard automatically create a chart for new sensor. So I wonder where would I be able to find examples and pointers for me to be able to do that?

Comment: Nothing change from my previous comment because the sensor is already tagged with SENSOR_ID which also I presume will be populated once u add a new sensor. No example I can give because this is ur own project but the coding is a basic data retrival and formatting. Try to code a simple data retrival with PHP first to get the project forward. Once u hv that, then only u worry about the new sensor added

Comment: Hello @zimorok, 

Thank you for the help. I am able to pull data for each sensor and plot it to the graphs. I have no issues with that. As you say, I am at the stage where I want to implement AUTOGENERATION of charts rather than hardcoding them into the dashboard. 

I will do some more research and see if I can find examples of which would put me on the right track. 

Thank you once again :)